# Asserting that a callback/listener is called in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I'm trying to find the cleanest/fastest way to test that a callback (which happens on the same thread) gets executed, and that it gets executed only once.

My best effort looks a like this:

```
    class Called {
        boolean value;
    }

    ...
    Called called = new Called();
    object.execute(new Listener() {
        public void onExecuted() {
            assertFalse(called.value);
            called.value = true;
        }
    }
    assertTrue(called.value);
    ...
```

Is that as good as it gets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/):

```
import org.mockito.Mockito.*;

...

@Test
public void Test {
    Listener listener = mock(Listener.class);

    object.execute(listener);

    verify(listener).onExecuted();
}
```